# scanf() with two variables but one input?

Tags: c, variables, scanf

I was wondering if you can do something like:

```
printf("\nEnter kwh used (for 7 economy tariff, enter Peak usage)\n");
scanf("%d",&kwh,&peak);
```

I guess it won't work but is there any way to get similar effect. I hope you know what I mean. I'm trying to get either one (peak or kwh) out of one scanf so it can later be passed onto appropriate function.

Comment: maybe you want to split the number in digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same value in both variables, you should do that yourself:

```
int kwh, peak;

if (scanf("%d",&kwh) == 1)
{
    peak = kwh;
}
else
{
    // complain
}
```